# A package was installed badly. How to remove it?

Tags: 12.10, updates, uninstall, command-line

When I'm trying to update or install anything I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package equalx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I tried to install `equalx_0.51.deb` but it failed.

I tested some commands like `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but it was not solved.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/add-applications/C/removing.html

Comment: Software Center Crashes.

Comment: Try Synaptic Package Manager

Comment: @CutieKrait  updated , glance it.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your terminal and type

```
sudo dpkg -r equalx
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

update:

As you have mentioned you got .deb file. Now in your terminal do as

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite equalx_0.51.deb
```

then try with what you would like to do.

hope that helps.

Comment: first line has this error: dpkg: error processing equalx (--remove):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 equalx

Comment: @CutieKrait you are welcome my Friend,:)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get remove equalx --purge` (purge will remove all the dependent libraries).

Have you tried using the repository for `equalx` instead of the `debian` file?

Comment: again the same error:             

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package equalx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

equalx is not in repository